# Images are not being displayed on php

Tags: php, image, file, printf, echo

I have a txt file that has in it a painting id. This painting id is the same as the name of the image. For example in the txt file the painting id is 00000 and the name of the images in the path I wrote in my echo statement is `00000.jpg`.

What I'm trying to do is to display all the images using this `for` loop and `echo` statement. But for some reason the images are not displaying. Whats displaying instead is [thats what is being displayed instead of the images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEh3H.png). Can anyone help me solve this problem please?

```
 <?php 
 $paintings = file('paintings.txt') or die('ERROR: Cannot find file');
 $delimiter = '~';
 foreach ($paintings as $painting){
    $paintingFields = explode($delimiter, $painting);
    $painting_id = $paintingFields[0];
}
for($i=0;$i<count($paintings); $i++){
echo "<img src='resources/paintings/square-medium/%s.jpg' . $painting_id></br>"; 

} 

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `echo` wrong. If you view the source of your generated page you'll see the literal '%s' in the code.

To use '%s' as a format string, use `sprintf()`:

```
echo sprintf("<img src='resources/paintings/square-medium/$s.jpg'></br>", $painting_id);
```

Or:

```
echo "<img src='resources/paintings/square-medium/" . $painting_id . ".jpg'></br>";
```

Even better, just do the ouputting in PHP mode:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($paintings); $i++){
?>
 <img src="resources/paintings/square-medium/<?= $painting_id ?>.jpg"><br>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Dont use `echo sprintf`. You got `printf()`

Comment: `echo "<img src='resources/paintings/square-medium/" . $painting_id . ".jpg'` this example is odd - if you're using double quoted strings you can just use `echo "<img src='resources/paintings/square-medium/$painting_id.jpg' ...` :). "Even better" is quite subjective btw.

Comment: I'd add `{}` for better readability: `square-medium/{$painting_id}.jpg'`

Comment: @AD7six I was trying to follow OP's style of breaking the string and using `.` concatenation, even though I agree it's odd. I that particular case, I'd say your method is "even better" :)